# Sort a list of images uploaded with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

In my application users can upload multiple images with Carrierwave. These images are displayed with Fotorama library.

I want to add a feature that would let users sort the images how she likes.

Currently I am using PostgreSQL with a JSON column like in the docs of the gem. The images path is below:
[image]

My code:

**In the form:**

```
<%= f.file_field :imagens, multiple: true, class: "float-left" %>
```

**In the model**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploaders :imagens, ImagemUploader
end
```

Comment: You want the user to be able to sort images on the frontend once or save the ordering in the backend?

Comment: @TheWhizofOz  first thanks for the Improvements on the question. Yes the idea is the user sort the sequence on the front end in the created/edit method and in show method these images are displayed in that sequence.

Comment: Please see these railscasts, which can greatly help you: http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax and http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns and http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists - the principles are the same.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have read both but still can't figured out how applied to my case. So I have that column that can have allot of images path, how I'm gonna bring that to the view for the user sort as he wish?